# submit only checked items

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to submit only these rows which is checked. I'm using [this jquery plungin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multiple-Table-Row-Selection/)  and my table looks same as is in link

```
@model IEnumerable<BillBox.ACD_UNI_STUDENTS>

<table class="table tblSelect">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkall" title="Select all" />
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FIRST_NAME)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LAST_NAME)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PERSONAL_NUMBER)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ACD_UNI_DEGREES.DEGREE)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ACD_UNI_FACULTIES.FACULTY)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ACD_UNI_SEMESTERS.SEMESTER)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ACD_UNI_SPECIALIZATIONS.SPECIALIZATION)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.COR_PAYER_STATUS.NAME)
        </th>

    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FIRST_NAME)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LAST_NAME)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PERSONAL_NUMBER)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ACD_UNI_FACULTIES.FACULTY)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ACD_UNI_SEMESTERS.SEMESTER)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ACD_UNI_SEMESTERS.SEMESTER)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ACD_UNI_SPECIALIZATIONS.SPECIALIZATION)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.COR_PAYER_STATUS.NAME)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Now I have a question. How can I retrieve ***only these rows*** which checkbox is checked?

that's my controller

```
public PartialViewResult AllStudent()
 {
   var students = (from q in db.ACD_UNI_STUDENTS
                   select q).ToList();
   return PartialView(students);
 }
```

there are many rows (from db) so I can't do it with formcollection. I can't retrieve their names

Comment: Your checkboxes don't have a `name` attribute so they wont post back anything. And you don't appear to have a form so how are you posting  anyway. And what is the signature of the method you POST to? And test the dead link!

Comment: @StephenMuecke link edited

Comment: I had post method which had formcollection as a parameter but could not retrieve that. you have already mentioned that these has not name. Also I can't give custom name to it there are a lot rows. Can u give me an example how can i do that?

Comment: You can add attribute to your checkbox that will contain row number. Then select all the checkboxes in that table and by that attribute you will know which rows checkbox was checked

Comment: Depends on what you want. If you render the checkboxes as `<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="@item.someIdProperty" />` and then post back to `public ActionResult Something(int[] id)` the value of `id` will be a collection of the checkbox values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may submit the selected ids as IEnumerable and then filter them in your controller! Here is an example

```
  <form action="url" method="post">
  ...
  @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Objs[]"  id="Objs[]" value="@item.UNIQUE_ID"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FIRST_NAME)
        </td>
  </tr>
  }...
    </form>
```

and your controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult AllStudent(IEnumerable<long> Objs)
    {
      var students = (from q in db.ACD_UNI_STUDENTS
                      where Objs.Contains(q.UNIQUE_ID)
                      select q).ToList();
      return PartialView(students);
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest not to use the Database Model for the View directly. You should have a Model to bind to the Rows, which might look like:

```
public class StudentRowViewModel
{
   public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
   public int StudentId { get; set; }

   // ... More columns, whatever you want to display
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When populating the View, you select `StudentRowViewModels` like this:

```
db.ACD_UNI_STUDENTS.Select(x => new StudentRowViewModel { StudentId = x.UNIQUE_ID, Name = ... });
```

Or whatever applies to your DataBase Model.

In your View, your Checkbox will also Bind to the Model:

```
@Html.CheckboxFor(x => x.IsChecked)
```

Finally, when the Form is submitted, you can select only the checked Items:

```
public ActionResult AllStudents(IEnumerable<StudentRowViewModel> model)
{
    var checked = model.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.StudentId).ToList();
    var items = db.ACD_UNI_STUDENTS.Where(x => checked.Contains(x.UNIQUE_ID));
}
```

You get the Idea?

Comment: thanks for advice. I have one question. Why should not I use database model as my model class? It's bad practice?

Comment: @George, I'd consider it bad practice for some reasons: First is security related, you might reveal knowledge about your Database Schema to the Presentation layer, which an attacker might use. Second is also security related: There is a higher chance that you make data accessible which is in your DB Model (e.g. a Credit Card Number) which you didn't want to be displayed. Third is, actually this example: Your view requires more functionality or different behaviour than your DB Model offers. A last good reason: When your DB Model changes, you don't need to change the UI, just a few adapting bits

Answer (score 0):

First put a class and value attribute in your checkbox :

```
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" value="@item.PERSONAL_NUMBER" />
```

Then i advise you to use a JQuery script to detect which checkbox are checked :

I suppose that you have a button to do another action :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#myButton').click(function() {
     var id = '';
      $('.myCheckBox:checked').each(function (e) {
        id += $(this).val() + ';'
        }
       var url = '/ControllerName/ActionResultName';
     $.ajax({
     url:url,
     cache: false,
     type: 'POST',
     data: {
       Id: id
        },
     succes: function(data){
        $('.myCheckBox').attr('checked',false);
        location.reload();
     }
    })
}
 });
```

After that you can get in your controller all the personnal numbers in your controller :

put a string parameter 'id' to your actionresult.

```
id.TrimEnd(';')
```